# Relative paths in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create an AWS lambda Function using terraform. 
My terraform directory looks like

- terraform

  - iam-policies

    - main.tf
  - lambda

    - files/
    - main.tf
  - main.tf

I have my lambda function stored inside **/terraform/lambda/files/lambda_function.py**.

Whenever I terraform apply, I have a "null_resource" that executes some commands in local machine that will zip the python file

```
variable "pythonfile" {
  description = "lambda function python filename"
  type        = "string"
}

resource "null_resource" "lambda_preconditions" {
  triggers {
    always_run = "${uuid()}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "rm -rf ${path.module}/files/zips"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "mkdir -p ${path.module}/files/zips"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "cp -R ${path.module}/files/${var.pythonfile} ${path.module}/files/zips/lambda_function.py"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "cd ${path.module}/files/zips && zip -r lambda.zip ."
  }
}
```

My "aws_lambda_function" resource looks like this.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
  filename         = "${path.module}/files/zips/lambda.zip"
  function_name    = "${format("%s-%s-%s-lambda-function", var.name, var.environment, var.function_name)}"
  role             = "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn}"
  handler          = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
  source_code_hash = "${base64sha256(format("%s/files/zips/lambda.zip", path.module))}", length(path.cwd) + 1, -1)}")}"
  runtime          = "${var.function_runtime}"
  timeout          = "${var.function_timeout}"
  memory_size      = "${var.function_memory}"

  environment {
    variables = {
      region      = "${var.region}"
      name        = "${var.name}"
      environment = "${var.environment}"
    }
  }

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = ["${var.subnet_ids}"]
    security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.lambda_sg.id}"]
  }

  depends_on = [
    "null_resource.lambda_preconditions"
  ]
}
```

**Problem:**
Whenever I change the lambda_function.py file and terraform apply again, everything works fine but the actual code in the lambda function do not change.
Also if I delete all the terraform state files and apply again, the new change is propagated without any problem.

What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: Can you precise "everything works fine but the actual code in the lambda function do not change"? Because it seems like everything is not working fine here (at least, not what you expect). What is the output of `terraform apply` when you make a change to `lambda_function.py`? Does it creates a new zip? Does it update `lambda_function` resource?

Comment: @norbjd whenever I fresh terraform apply, it creates the zip file and uploads the code to lambda without any errors. But when I change the code in the lambda_function.py and terraform apply, the expected result would be an update in the function code in the Lambda console. But actually, the change in the lambda_function.py is not propagated to the lambda function. There is no error in second attempt.

Comment: Is the zip with updated code created by the second `terraform apply`?

Comment: @norbjd yes, the second apply creates the updated zip but somehow the code in Lambda isn't changed. I checked the zip also has updated code in it.

Comment: By the way, the `source_code_hash` syntax is wrong (not the same number of closing parentheses/brackets as opening). After the first `apply`, what is its computed value? If after the second `apply` the `source_code_hash` is the same, that's why the lambda is not updated (because other computed arguments are the same).

Comment: To quickly test if the `source_code_hash` expression is your problem, you can always use `source_code_hash = "${timestamp()}"` to force an update every time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of using `null_resource`, I used the `archive_file` data source that creates the zip file automatically if new changes are detected. Next I took a reference from the archive_file data in the lambda resource `source_code_hash` attribute.

**archive_file data source**

```
data "archive_file" "lambda_zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = "${path.module}/files/zips/lambda.zip"

  source {
    content  = "${file("${path.module}/files/ebs_cleanup_lambda.py")}"
    filename = "lambda_function.py"
  }
}
```

**The lambda resource**

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
  filename         = "${path.module}/files/zips/lambda.zip"
  function_name    = "${format("%s-%s-%s-lambda-function", var.name, var.environment, var.function_name)}"
  role             = "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn}"
  handler          = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_base64sha256}"
  runtime          = "${var.function_runtime}"
  timeout          = "${var.function_timeout}"
  memory_size      = "${var.function_memory}"

  environment {
    variables = {
      region      = "${var.region}"
      name        = "${var.name}"
      environment = "${var.environment}"
    }
  }

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = ["${var.subnet_ids}"]
    security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.lambda_sg.id}"]
  }
}
```